# Deploying an Azure Function using RBAC on ubuntu-latest (Linux)

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions

I've been trying to figure out if deploying an Azure Function to Linux via RBAC actually works.  I've seen other posts and bug reports over the last 4 years and all have no solution.

I can deploy an Azure Function to Linux via a Publish Profile, but that doesn't scale well to deploying many functions and I would prefer to use RBAC.

I've tried deploying via RBAC with GitHub Actions and receive:

Error: Execution Exception (state: PublishContent) (step: Invocation)
Error:   When request Azure resource at PublishContent, Sync Trigger Functionapp : Failed to perform sync trigger on function app. Function app may have malformed content. Please manually restart your function app and inspect the package from WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE.
Error: Deployment Failed!

I've also tried deploying directly from Azure CLI like so:  az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g dev -n test-function --src app.zip and get 'Bad Request' being returned as an error here.

Further debugging shows that its a call to /syncfunctiontriggers that is failing with a "BadGateway" request...  (This is the API call that is failing in both GitHub Actions and Azure CLI).

Any ideas?

Thank you,

James

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

RBAC with GitHub Actions can work but I found a few things to keep in mind:

1. The Azure/functions-action does not seem to work at all with RBAC deployment on ubuntu-latest...  For Publish Profile it works great.
2. I worked around this by using a CLI command from my github action - az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <resource_group> -n  --src app.zip.
3. Be careful when using the .zip command and ensure your executable files/dlls etc are at the root of the .zip.
4. If you have a function that is continuously crashing or buggy (like I did because of another problem) it may not deploy correctly, and you'll get weird errors on the az functionapp deployment command.
5. If you run into this problem you can delete the Function App Configuration setting for WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE.  This will stop loading the old version of your app (and crashing it), and allow you to deploy properly.

Hope this helps.  :-)